# jQuery Flickering

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails 3 application w/ the following in one of my views:

```
<li class = "comment">
  ...some comment text...
  <ul class = "actions">
    <li><a href = "#">Edit</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Then in my application.js

```
$('.comment').live('mouseover',function() {
  $(this).show();
}).live('mouseout',function(){
  $(this).hide();
});
```

The problem is that when you move your mouse over `.comment` mouseover seems to get called repeatedly which causes `.actions` to flicker. I have tried replacing `mouseover/mouseout` with `mouseenter/mouseleave` which somewhat solves the problem. `.actions` does not flicker when hovering over `.comment` but it will then flicker horribly when you hover over top of the `.actions` itself.

Comment: You're missing a couple closing quotes in that code, I assume that's just a result of formatting it for entry here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event gets called more than once due to event bubbling, what you want to do is:

```
$('.comment .actions').live('mouseover',function(e) {
  $(this).show();
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}).live('mouseout',function(e){
  $(this).hide();
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Alex! This is exactly what I'm looking for. I've been pulling my hair out on this for like the past hour.

Comment: @Kyle no prob, glad to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add a mouseover event on a hidden element. If it has a `display:none` (`$(this).hide()`), it can't be mouseover'd and as such it won't call the event either. I think you may have been wanting to do this instead:

```
  $('.actions').hide();
   $('.comment').live('mouseover',function() {
  $(this).children('.actions').show();
}).live('mouseout',function(){
  $(this).children('.actions').hide();
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/9GPVu/8/

If that wasn't what you were looking for, the problem could be in your markup as well cause it is broken in many parts, such as no ending quote for `a href`, or `ul class`.

Comment: The no ending quotes was just a typo when I was writing out my question. It's correct in my actual source code. I'll try your solution though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the actions links to show up when a user hovers over the comment, then I think this is more along the lines of what you want:

```
$('.comment').live('mouseover',function() {
  $(this).find('.actions').show();
}).live('mouseout',function(){
  $(this).find('.actions').hide();
});
```

Comment: That's actually what I have in my source. I just typed incorrectly on here.